# NLP Negation detection and Stop Words

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'd like to improve my sentiment analysis via negation detection. I'm implementing sentiment analysis using a bag of words approach highlight by professor, hence why I'm not using CoreNLP's sentiment annotator, yet. However, I noticed it has a problem.

Given the sentence, "I'm not disappointed in them", I would expect, at worst, a neutral sentiment, or weakly positive sentiment, both from the sentiment annotator, and my own bag of words implementation. The sentiment annotator reports this sentence as negative.

```
I: PRP  Neutral
'm: VBP Neutral
not: RB Negative
disappointed: VBN   Negative
in: IN  Neutral
them: PRP   Neutral
.: .    Neutral
Negative
1
```

The last two lines show the sentence's sentiment label and the numerical sentiment score.

How do I improve the sentiment annotator's chances of getting this right, and how can I use CoreNLP to detect negation like what's shown, negation across sentences, and references to an entity across multiple sentences (which seems like the coref and dcoref annotators)?

Also, potentially useful would be getting rid of stop words. The lemma annotator seems to take care of stemming, but which annotator does stop words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `natlog` annotator, every token will be marked with a `NaturalLogicAnnotations.PolarityAnnotation`.  So negated words will have a polarity of `down`.

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;

import java.util.*;


public class NaturalLogicExample {

  public static String text = "I'm not disappointed in them.";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set up pipeline properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    // set the list of annotators to run
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,natlog");
    // build pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // create a document object
    CoreDocument document = new CoreDocument(text);
    // annnotate the document
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    for (CoreLabel token : document.tokens()) {
      System.out.println(String.format("%s\t%s", token.word(),
          token.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.PolarityAnnotation.class)));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I should be able to use this! I was hoping to read more about `natlog`, but the link embedded in this page: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/natlog.html gets a 404. Do you have a link to more detail on `natlog`? Also, does CoreNLP have a stemmer, and a stopword remover? Is the `lemma` annotator sufficient for stemming?

Comment: any suggestions on reading material for the `natlog` annotator, and on the stemminng and stopping part of the question?

Comment: lemma is probably best you get for stemming

Comment: I don't believe we have any stop word handling